# How to launch another program in GUI (python tkinter)

Tags: python, user-interface, process, background

i wrote a simple GUI using Python Tkinter. When i click a button it launches another program. But the GUI window stays there waiting for the the program to exit. I want the GUI to launch the program on Button1 and I can click on Button2 to run the test. I used os.system() to launch the program. Pls advise.

thanks
maximus

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `os.system()` will wait.

As the documentation for os.system() points out, you might want to replace it by using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) module, where there are many different ways to start commands and where you can choose if you want to wait for it to finish or not.